# Replace everything that starts with number python

Tags: python, csv, replace

I am working with ICD-9 codes for a data mining project using python and I am having trouble converting the specific codes into categories. For example, I am trying to change everything that's between 001 and 139 with 0, everything that's between 140 and 239 with 1, etc

This is what I have tried:

```
df = df.replace({'diag_1' : {'(1-139)' : 0, '(140-239)' : 1}})
```

Comment: You can use `pd.cut` to set the bucket intervals and also set the category values: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html, you can then override the existing values with the labels, if you see the example in the link you will understand what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pd.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) to achieve this:

```
In [175]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':np.random.randint(0,20,10)})
df

Out[175]:
   value
0     12
1      2
2     10
3      5
4     19
5      2
6      8
7     14
8     12
9     16
```

here we set bin intervals of (0-5) (5-15), (15-20):

```
In [183]:    
df['new_value'] = pd.cut(df['value'], bins=[0,5,15,20], labels=[0,1,2])
df

Out[183]:
   value new_value
0     12         1
1      2         0
2     10         1
3      5         0
4     19         2
5      2         0
6      8         1
7     14         1
8     12         1
9     16         2
```

I think in your case the following should work:

```
df['diag_1']= pd.cut(df['diag_1'], [1,140,240] , labels=[1,2,3])
```

you can set the bins and labels dynamically using `np.arange` or similar

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with an if-statement.

```
newvalue = 1 if oldvalues <= 139 else 2
```

Apply this function as a lambda expression with `map`.